# SQL Server 2008 - Median for Multiple Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, median

I am attempting to create Medians for several columns using multiple fields in the group by section, below is the current setup of the data:

```
ZIP     City    State   Males   Females Tall    Short  
1   New York    NY      1000    1500    1250    1250  
2   New York    NY      500     700     400     800  
3   New York    NY      800     1200    900     1100  
4   Chicago     IL      900     750     850     800  
5   Chicago     IL      250     800     100     950  
6   Chicago     IL      650     325     725     250
```

I am looking for the output to look something similar to this:

```
ZIP     City    State   Males   Females Tall    Short  [Median Males]   [Median Females]     [Median Tall]  [Median Short]
1   New York    NY      1000    1500    1250    1250  
2   New York    NY      500     700     400     800  
3   New York    NY      800     1200    900     1100  
4   Chicago     IL      900     750     850     800  
5   Chicago     IL      250     800     100     950  
6   Chicago     IL      650     325     725     250
```

There are many other fields and much more information that I need to create medians for, ~100 columns.  I know how to do this for single columns, but I am getting stuck on creating this for more than 1 at a time.

Thanks for the help.
Keith

Comment: Construct the aggregate+key in a subquery, and join back to the full data on the key.

Comment: I am currently using a subquery to pull in the Median since it is not a defined aggregate function in SQL, unfortunately I am not sure how to use the query on multiple columns. I apologize, I am new to this forum and am not sure how to format this correctly.  This is the code:   SELECT STATE, AVG(1.0*MALES) MALES
FROM
(
   SELECT STATE, MALES, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY MALES), 
      c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY STATE)
   FROM dbo.MEDIAN
)
AS x
WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
GROUP BY STATE